# Анимация появления блока (div) + смена по клику

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на первую кнопку выводился первый блок, на вторую -второй. При этом повторные нажатия не меняли блоки местами, а кнопки внутри блоков работали как и работают.

[Вот пример](https://codepen.io/REDiRECT/pen/aERyeP)  который необходимо доработать.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
      $('.switch-form').toggleClass('start-anim');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 80px auto;
}

.zakaz-form {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #49c766;
  transform: translateX(-250%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.cons-form {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f03e53;
  transform: translateX(250%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.start-anim {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Первая кнопка</button>
<button>Вторая кнопка</button>
<div class="zakaz-form switch-form"><button class="btn cons-button">Показать второй блок</button></div>
<div class="cons-form switch-form start-anim"><button class="btn zakaz-button">Показать первый блок</button></div>
```

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде я тебя правильно понял

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
      $('.switch-form').toggleClass('start-anim');
    });
  });
  $(function() {
    $('.btn1').click(function() {
      $('.switch-form').addClass('start-anim');
      $('.zakaz-form').removeClass('start-anim');
    });
  });
  $(function() {
    $('.btn2').click(function() {
      $('.switch-form').removeClass('start-anim');
      $('.zakaz-form').addClass('start-anim');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  margin: 80px auto;
}

.zakaz-form {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #49c766;
  transform: translateX(-250%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.cons-form {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(50% - 100px);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #f03e53;
  transform: translateX(250%);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.start-anim {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn1">Первая кнопка</button>
<button class="btn2">Вторая кнопка</button>
<div class="zakaz-form switch-form"><button class="btn cons-button">Показать второй блок</button></div>
<div class="cons-form switch-form start-anim"><button class="btn zakaz-button">Показать первый блок</button></div>
```

Comment: То что нужно!) Спасибо Вам ещё раз, просто спасли, два дня голову ломал) И отдельное спасибо за то, что научили как код правильно в пост вставлять)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стала "плодить" лишний код. можно попробовать немного обобщить класс для переключения кнопок

```
<button class="js-toggleform" data-form="cons">Первая кнопка</button>
<button data-form="zakaz" class="js-toggleform">Вторая кнопка</button>


<div class="zakaz-form switch-form"><button class="btn cons-button js-toggleform" data-form="cons">Показать второй блок</button></div>
<div class="cons-form switch-form start-anim"><button class="btn zakaz-button js-toggleform" data-form="zakaz">Показать первый блок</button></div>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $('.js-toggleform').click(function(event) {
      var needDiv = $(event.currentTarget).data('form');
      $('.switch-form').removeClass('start-anim');
      $('.'+needDiv+'-form').addClass('start-anim');
    });
  });
});
```

В итоге, есть один общий класс js-toggleform. по клику проверяем дата-атрибут data-form="cons", с помощью которого находим нужный блок. и показываем

Comment: Благодарю за участие!) Да, так действительно короче, но у меня нет возможности использовать дата-атрибут и первый вариант подходит больше, но вот на будущее в черновик запишу) спасибо)